# How to make a java controller with facade design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a java project where I've written the domain layer and want to implement a controller using singleton and facade design pattern so that a gui only have to instantiate the controller object once. After the controller object is called I would like the other controllers to be accessed through the frontcontroller.

So fx. if you want to create a new account from the view:

```
public static FrontController controller = new FrontController();
controller.employee.createAccount("name of user");
```

to give a better overview here is the file structure:

```
|> controller
| --> EmployeeController.java
| --> ProjectController.java
| --> FrontController.java
|> view
| --> Init.java
| --> index.fxml
| --> Controller.java
|> domain
| --> Employee.java
| --> Project.java
```

Here is the frontcontroller; The other controller files are not written yet:

```
package controller;

public class FrontController {
       
    private static final FrontController instance  = new FrontController();
    
    private FrontController(){}
    
    public static FrontController getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    EmployeeController employee = new EmployeeController();
    ProjectController project = new ProjectController();
    
    
}
```

I'm currently pretty lost and pretty unsure if it's even possible to make a controller like this. My idea for this facade pattern and singleton is that you can have a static field in the frontend that any page can call so that it then becomes very easy to talk to the backend. I can't figure out if I need another design pattern for this or if this is pure anti-pattern.
This MVC stuff is pretty new to me without spring so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expose EmployeeController / ProjectController, wrap the relevant methods and delegate to the real impl.

```
public class FrontController {
{
  private EmployeeController employee = new EmployeeController();
  private ProjectController project = new ProjectController();

  //.....

  public createAccount(....) {
    return this.employee.createAccount(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. but this method would require all methods implemented by the frontcontroller are within the frontcontroller class. I was thinking if it was possible to just create the objects fx. and call classobject.object.someMethodInsideEmployeeController

Comment: I just feel like if i have all methods inside the frontcontroller it's gonna become messy really fast

Comment: often you'll need more than one backend call for a frontend action. Instead of calling x controller methods you can group them to a "higher level" function per use case in the frontend controller... depends on the use case / method structure